# Xcode8.3-Invalid bitcode signature

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

First of all, I know this question is duplicated but I can't find the answer to solve my problem and most of the discussion is about `cocoapods` whereas I am using `Carthage`.

I am using `Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)`, updated yesterday to `Carthage version 0.23.0`, update just now `carthage update --platform iOS` or `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries`

What I tried

1. Cleaning Derived data folder and reopen Xcode. I deleted all files in Derived data and clean project => reopen Xcode => failed
2. `Build Active Architecture Only` set to `YES`
   Setting to `YES` or `NO` doesn't work
3. Setting **ALL** `Bitcode enabled` to `NO`
   At first, I only setting `Bitcode` in my project, doesn't work
   then I set every project in `Carthage/Checkouts`
   then `carthage update --platform iOS`, doesn't work

above are what I tried, any idea that something I missing or any step I'm wrong, e.g. you should do `A` then `C` then `B` rather than `ABC`

**UPDATE**
The error disappear, but I'm not sure what exactly I do The final config is
`Build Active Architecture Only`: `Debug = YES`, `Release = NO`
`Bitcode enabled = NO`, my project only, project in Carthage keep its original setting
*Then*
add the framework to

```
target/General/Linked Frameworks and Libraries` and `target/Build Phases/THE_SCRIPT
```

I'm not sure if this step affect but after I add, build success

Answer (score 3):

It works to me, setting `Build Active Architecture only`-> `Debug:YES, Release:NO`, and `Enable Bitcode` -> `NO`.

Comment: This fixed it for me too, thank you! The error started happening after I added a new pod to the Today extension. I vaguely remember I had to do similar fix (with different error message) for the main app.

Comment: Fixed it for me too.  I also had just added a new pod and began getting this invalid bitcode signature error.